# Select from list without having identifier

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am using linq to get data from website to List:

```
var HTMLTable = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"users_table\"]")).Select(e => e.Text).ToList();
```

Then I am using Console to see that data is in the List:

```
HTMLTable.ForEach(i => Console.Write("{0}\t", i));
```

Console shows table data as follow:

```
Firstname 
Lastname 
Type 
Crew 
JobTitle
DefaultPrice 
Future 
Language
```

Now I want to create a new list where Crew = "Employer". How to do that without having "column" names?

I have tried:

```
var OnlyOwnEmployees = HTMLTable.Where(x => x.[0] == "Employer").ToList();
```

But it says identifier expected and pointing to zero.

Comment: Use Where in place of Select

Comment: @viveknuna Yes, my bad. Should be Where. However this seems to be still producing an error with message identifier expeced

Comment: It should be x.Crew

Comment: We need to see a structure of your users_table. You've shown us a list of a string containing column names only and we can't see much from your XPath selector so it's hard to tell you how to get the actual data from the table and filter it by certain column value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Where` not `Select`. It should be `.Where(x => x.Crew`

Comment: This would work otherwise but my columns/datatypes are anonymous. So it does not recognize `Crew`